# Unique Identifiers for classes - Java with Spring

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, spring

My use case requires me to implement multiple validators which implement the interface:

```
public interface Validator {
 boolean validate(Object o);
}
```

Based on the business group of the Object o, a different combination of validators need to be applied.

For each business group, I plan to maintain a list of Validators.
This list will be maintained in an external configuration store.
Ex:

```
BusinessGroupA {
 Validators = [v1,v2,v3,v4]
}

BusinessGroupB {
 Validators = [v3,v6]
}
```

What seems to be a good way to uniquely identify each validator from the list?
Should v1,v2 be spring ids corresponding to their respective validators or do I need to explicitly create a unique identifier for each such validator and map that internally through a hashmap in my code?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: _Why_ do you need to uniquely identify each validator from the list? Wouldn't you just apply each validator to the object in sequence?

Answer (score 5):

**Use an identifier that has an explicit name.**
Validators with explicit names make your code so much more readable: instead of `BusinessGroupA` having validators 'v1', 'v2', 'v3' and 'v4' the `CustomerOrderGroup` is validated by the `NoOutstandingPaymentsValidator`, `SufficientCreditValidator`...

Comment: Thanks for the response!
My only concern with that approach is possible duplication / name clash of two different validators.
Is there some way to effectively eliminate that?

Comment: Yeah, it's called a compiler.  These are class names not simply strings.

Comment: Yeah, well if these 'identifiers' are class names this question would make no sense. It is clearly stated that v1 would be an id and I am making the case for these id's being in a human-understandable format.

Comment: I can't imagine any descriptive validator name clashing, but I'm not aware of the domain you are working in so I might be wrong. You might end up with some rather long names to guarantee 'uniqueness' but as long as those names are descriptive length should rarely be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
Are there any design related flaws with this approach (i.e. maintaining validators in the config) or is there any better,alternative way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

**Use a dependency injection (or IoC) framework.**

What you are describing is a dependency injection framework which will load your dependencies for you via configuration.

[Spring offers a DI framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans).